# Multiple If (and (isnumber (search.... First clause works but subsequent clause' fails

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I am using O365 and am having trouble with this formula looking at two cells and returning the appropriate value based on those cell's values.

I have two columns: Vendors and Amount.  Vendors will have multiple instances of the same company - USAA, for example, with varying dollar values in the Amount column.

I have three customers, John, Marie, and Kaleb, who are all insured by USAA but their dollar amounts vary based upon USAA criteria.  John's amount is $48.23, Marie's is $19.57, and Kaleb's is $33.45.

What I want is:

1. Return a single value based upon the values shown under Vendor (Col A) and Amount (Col B).

Here is what I wrote:

```
=If (and (isnumber (search ("*USAA*", A2)), (search ("48.23", B2))), "John", If (and (isnumber (search ("*USAA*", A2)), (search ("19.57", B2))), "Marie", If (and (isnumber (search ("*USAA*", A2)), (search ("33.45", B2))), "Kaleb"
```

If the value in B2 = $48.23, then C2 accurately displays "John"; however, when that value is any other number, it only display a #Value! error message.

Comment: YOu do not wrap the second search in Isnumber.

Comment: Thank you, but can you elaborate?  What do I need to do to correct what I have written?

Comment: So, breaking the formula apart into lines at the parens, using notepad++, I think that I see: 1) an extra `)` immediately before `, "Marie"` and; 2) no closing `)` at the end of the formula. Not an answer because I do not know if the formula works with these corrections.

Comment: seems like you can restructure your `IF` formula to first see if A2 contains `*USAA*` if yes, then proceed with your second criteria for B2 as a bunch of nested `if`, or `IFS`, which if I'm not mistaken can be shorted to `B2=48.23` (as one example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*USAA*",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("48.23",B2))),"John",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*USAA*",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("19.57",B2))),"Marie",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*USAA*",A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("33.45",B2))),"Kaleb")))`

Comment: @Dr_Xunil...I hate that I was so far off of my intention but I am still learning.  Your solution worked perfectly and I greatly appreciate you for taking the time.

Comment: I believe the reason yours did not initially work was due to the way the Search() function evaluates your input. The more you work at it, it easier it becomes, so keep at it!